# Perform postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-11

I use Postgres 11.5. 
I try to perform the following select.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;

CREATE TABLE test (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    version VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    data JSONB NOT NULL,
    publishedAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (version, type, data, publishedAt) 
SELECT  '1.0.0', 'article', '{"tags":[{"slug":"complexes"}]}', '2019/11/11 11:11:11' 
FROM generate_series(1, 100000);

explain analyse 
SELECT id 
FROM test 
WHERE version = '1.0.0'  
  AND type = 'article' 
  AND data @> '{"tags":[{"slug":"complexes"}]}' 
ORDER BY publishedAt 
DESC LIMIT 20;
```

I try to add indexes but the select took at least 62ms.

Have you any idea to find a way to decrease the execution time of the select under 10ms?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the execution plan as formatted text. Make sure you preserve the indention.

Comment: An index won't help as all rows have the same values in the columns and your query will return all 100000 rows and all those rows need to be sorted. If you want to test performance you need to create more realistic test data.

Comment: What indexes have you tried?